# How can I unpivot data using scala and maps?

Tags: scala, dictionary, unpivot

I am preparing a few views for some data I'm working in, and to better summarize them, I need to group and Pivot them

after grouping I get this data

`Key  Col1_7days  Col2_7_days Col1_30days  Col2_30_days
 0       0.0053      0.0049      0.0061        0.0073`

I'm trying to get something like

`Col  7days  30days
Col1  0.0053 0.0061 
Col2  0.0049 0.0061`

for this I've created two maps

```
map1 =Seq((Col1_7days, Col1),
          (Col1_30days, Col1),
          (Col2_7days, Col2),
          (Col2_30days, Col2))

map2 = Seq((Col1_7days, 7days),
          (Col1_30days,  30days),
          (Col2_7days,  7days),
          (Col2_30days, 30days))
```

the point is I can't "translate" the maps into the table.

any ideas?

Comment: To be honest I don't get your question. Can you show how your data is stored and in which data structures? Or maybe you're using spark?

Comment: two ways: Map[(Col,Row), Value] or Array of arrays. The first array can be either rows or columns